# Lodash filter negative numbers only and include zeros

Tags: javascript, lodash

Using lodash, the goal is to filter negative numbers. However, the following piece of code also filters zeros for some reason. Why is this happening and how can I include the zero's? I've tried changing `>=` to `>` and this still does not work (which is obviously wrong anyway).

```
let numbers =  [1,2,3,0,-1,4,0];

_.filter(numbers, (number) => {
     if (number >= 0) {
          return number;
     } 
 });
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

How can I include the zeros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to return the boolean expression in your `if` statement.

```
let result = _.filter(numbers, number => number >= 0);
```

Your code returns numeric values, wherein zeroes are evaluated as falsy and non-zeroes are evaluated as truthy. This is what's causing the filter to not include the zeroes.

```js
let numbers =  [1,2,3,0,-1,4,0];

let result = _.filter(numbers, number => number >= 0);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How could I've missed that?! Thanks!